# Add IAM capabilities to stack in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

In the `bin` directory in my CDK project I have this:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
import 'source-map-support/register';
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import {PipelineStack} from "../lib/pipeline-stack";

const app = new cdk.App();

new PipelineStack(app, 'PipelineStack', {
    env: {account: '12345678912', region: 'us-east-1'},
});

app.synth();
```

Where `PipelineStack` is defined as (in my `../lib` directory):

```js
import {Construct, Stack, StackProps} from '@aws-cdk/core';
import {CodePipeline, CodePipelineSource, ShellStep} from '@aws-cdk/pipelines';
import {HadesStage} from './hades-stage';

/**
 * The stack that defines the application pipeline
 */
export class PipelineStack extends Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const appName = 'MyApp';

        const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
            // The pipeline name
            pipelineName: 'MyAppPipeline',

            // How it will be built and synthesized
            synth: new ShellStep('Synth', {
                // Where the source can be found
                input: CodePipelineSource.gitHub('OWNER/REPO', 'master'),

                // Install dependencies, build and run cdk synth
                commands: [
                    'npm ci',
                    'npm run build',
                    'npx cdk synth'
                ],
            }),
        });

        pipeline.addStage(new MyAppStage(this, 'MyAppProdStage', 'Prod', appName, 'mydomain.com', {
            env: {account: '12345678912', region: 'us-east-1'}
        }));
    }
}
```

And `MyAppStage` is:

```js
import {Construct, Stage, StageProps} from '@aws-cdk/core';
import {HadesStack} from './hades-stack';

/**
 * Deployable unit of web service app
 */
export class MyAppStage extends Stage {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, stageName: string, appName: string, domainName: string, props?: StageProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        new MyAppStack(this, `${appName}${stageName}Stack`, stageName, appName, domainName, {
            stackName: `${appName}${stageName}Stack`,
        });
    }
}
```

And `MyAppStack` is a stack with my actual resources. Basically I followed [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/cdk-pipelines-continuous-delivery-for-aws-cdk-applications/).

It works fine, until I add a secret rotation for RDS credentials. The `MyAppStack` stack fails with:

```
Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND]
```

Which makes sense; however, I can't find a way to add the IAM capabilities to the stack through CDK. Am I doing something wrong? Or is the approach covered by the guide not meant to cover this? Can I add the capabilities somehow?

Comment: GitHub issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/15711

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this was, indeed, a bug, and [Otavio Macedo](https://github.com/otaviomacedo) fixed it in GitHub pull request [#15819](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/15819).